# Resolving dynamic object creation (inside another dynamically created object) with autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

i'm trying to create a module (that will be referenced in a simple ASP site, using the Autofac Web Form Integration) that has a particular requirement.
It should return a string created using a specific set of rules. Those rules are defined by a strategy, different for each "Actor". The "Actor" will be choosed at runtime depending on a value coming from the request. To make things harder, some "Actor" can have a different and specific implementation of this strategy based on, for example, the country of the request.

I have already solved this problem using an abstract and a concrete factory (the first to understand which "Actor" concrete factory use, the second one to determine if i need a specific or a generic actor's strategy). The problem is that, having adopted a strongly modular design, i need to use reflection in order to get an indirect reference to the specific actor's strategy class(otherwise i should have a reference to all the dll's containing all the specific strategy implementations).

I would love to avoid this approach, mostly because i would like to use a unique way to dynamically load the required components.

I've looked at some of the Autofac possibilities and from what i've understood, i can register different implementations of the same interface and resolve them using a key as explained here (https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/TypedNamedAndKeyedServices). The problem is that i don't know how to resolve them inside my abstract and concrete factories (i don't have a reference to the resolver there...and i think that i should avoid it).

So my questions are:

1) How can i use Autofac in that scenario? What is the best practice (surely i'm missing something HUGE)

2) Do i have to reconsider all the design of this module? I mean, do i still need to use an abstract and a concrete factory?

3) Can anyone point me to some example or tutorial maybe related to my problem?

Many thanks for your help, and sorry for the long and not-so-clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach would be to divide your strategies into generic ones and actor specific ones. You already did that in your head, but I don't know if your code reflects that.

- Have two interfaces `IActorSpecificStrategy` and `IGenericStrategy`.
- Add a method `bool CanHandleActor(IActor actor)` to both interfaces (or to the interface both derive from).
- Inject two enumerables into your factory: One that contains `IActorSpecificStrategy` and one that contains `IGenericStrategy`.
- When a strategy for an actor is requested, first enumerate all `IActorSpecificStrategy` instances and return the first for which `CanHandleActor` returns `true`. Otherwise, return the first `IGenericStrategy` for which `CanHandleActor` returns `true`.

If this is not applicable to your problem, please explain more detailed how the strategy is selected.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your amazingly fast response! I totally agree with your first two points, and i'll try to implement them as soon as i can. I just have a doubt about the last two points: Where should i perform the injection (i mean, who should be responsible to do that, i think it should be done in the configuration building during startup, right?). And, lastly, does this approach means that i will create an instance of all those strategies for each request (and use just one?) I think that autofac should handle those details for me, so i shouldn't bother, right?

Comment: @Gnegno: About the business point you mentioned in your first version: The two interfaces can very well be [marker interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) without any methods or properties at all. The injection is done by Autofac, normally in your composition root, so you shouldn't need to bother. Just give the strategy factory (actually, it now is a strategy *selector*) a constructor with those two enumerables. Normally, strategies don't save any state themselves, so they would be registered as singletons (`.SingleInstance()` in Autofac).

Comment: Yes, sorry for the first comment version...i've initially misunderstood the purpose of the interfaces. I think that your solution will perfectly fit my needs. I'll let you know as soon as i have a functional prototype. Many tanks in advance!

Comment: I've one last question. I've succesfully updated my test code to be compliant with the solution you've pointed, it seems easier and great! Now i've to configure Autofac in order to read all the strategies. Is that approach right?             builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(partnerAssembly).As<IPartnerStrategyBase>(); 
and, how can i do the next step (injecting all of the readed types in the selector)?

Comment: I've found the answer to the second question...sorry for the rush. i'll use container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IPartnerStrategyBase>>();

Comment: You usually don't need to resolve them yourself at all. Just resolve the factory selector, Autofac will resolve the constructor parameters itself. The registration should look something like this: `builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(partnerAssembly).AsImplementedInterfaces().SingleInstance();`